# JBoss EAP 6.1 + HornetQ cannot enable AIO

Tags: jboss6.x, hornetq

I'm trying to enalbe AIO on ERHL (6) running Jboss EAP 6.1 with messaging enabled (HornetQ). I enabled ASYNCIO in the journal-type, but when I start the server I get:

`13:00:00,307 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3)  JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal`

I know, 'libaio' is already installed:

`Package libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

What do I need to do to get it working?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default JBoss EAP 6 don't include `jbossas-hornetq-native` package. Take a look in the following links:

- [Installing Native Components and Utilities](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Installation_Guide/sect-Installing_Native_Components_and_Utilities.html#Download_and_Install_Native_Components_and_Native_Utilities)
- [Install Native Components and Native Utilities (RPM
  Installation)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Installation_Guide/Install_Native_Components_and_Native_Utilities_RPM_Installation.html)

---

```
$ yum groupinfo jboss-eap6
Group: JBoss EAP 6
 Mandatory Packages:
   jbossas-appclient
   jbossas-bundles
   jbossas-core
   jbossas-domain
   jbossas-hornetq-native
   jbossas-jbossweb-native
   jbossas-modules-eap
   jbossas-product-eap
   jbossas-standalone
   jbossas-welcome-content-eap
```

**jbossas-hornetq-native package**

```
$ rpm -ql jbossas-hornetq-native
/usr/share/jbossas/modules/org/hornetq/main/lib
/usr/share/jbossas/modules/org/hornetq/main/lib/linux-x86_64
/usr/share/jbossas/modules/org/hornetq/main/lib/linux-x86_64/libHornetQAIO.so
```

Note the `jbossas-hornetq-native` package is included for high availability in JBoss EAP 6 but it is not activated by default.